# Cannot Import Flask in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, pip

I am new to python. I am trying to import Flask a python script. But it is throwing an error. 

Here's my python script "*tokenize.py*"

```
from flask import Flask, Response
```

But I am getting the following error when running it:

```
$ python2.7 tokenize.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tokenize.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, Response  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 67, in <module>
    from werkzeug._internal import _get_environ
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_internal.py", line 13, in <module>
    import inspect
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/Users/abashir/tokenize.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, Response  
ImportError: cannot import name Flask
```

I am working on *MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6 (17G6S)*.

```
$ python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.10
```

In pip list:

```
$ pip list
Package                                Version 
-------------------------------------- --------
...
Flask                                  1.0.2
...
```

And when I try to re-install Flask

```
$ pip install Flask
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->Flask) (1.1.0)
```

What is the problem? and how to solve it?

Comment: Rename your file `tokenize.py` to something else.

Comment: It will depend on which version of Python your OS is defaulting to. Reason I mention that is because when you run pip install [library], pip will go and find the default python interpreter and use that instead of the one you want it to use. So you may have installed Flask using a completely different python interpreter. Do you have just python 2.7 installed or do you have python 3.x installed as well?

Comment: @bro-grammer I renamed it to ashraf.py, and it is still the same issue.

Comment: You might be better of using a virtualenv . Try `which python2.7`

Comment: @Naufal, yes I do have python 3 installed `$ python3 -V` > `Python 3.7.2`

Comment: @NihalSangeeth  `$ which python2.7` > `/usr/bin/python2.7`

Comment: I suggested you renaming because line 12 of your Traceback is trying to do `import tokenize` but failing due to name collision.

Comment: Try running `python2.7 -c "import flask"`, if no error pops up then the problem lies somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Ashraf so when you run "which python" (without 2.7), does it point to python3?

Comment: What happened if you run with python3 ?

Comment: Run this `python2.7 -c "from flask import Flask, Response"` on the terminal and see what is happening. If same error comes install Flask again `sudo pip install Flask --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall` and check.

Comment: @bro-grammer `python2.7 -c "import flask"` leads to the same issue

Comment: @Naufal `$ which python` > /usr/bin/python , 
`$ which python2.7` > /usr/bin/python2.7 , 
and `$ which python3` > /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: @Tarek, running it with `python3` causes the same error

Comment: @Ashraf try the following:"cd /usr/bin" and then do "ls -l *python*" (as you're on MacOS) and you should be able to see what python is redirected to e.g. python -> python2.7 (in my case). Also try "which pip" which will tell you which version of pip you're using. There's an alternative, try running python2.7 -m pip install flask then run your tokenize.py.

Comment: @RamIdavalapati running `python2.7 -c "from flask import Flask, Response"` causes same issue. I run `sudo pip install Flask --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall` and it successfully finished `Successfully installed Jinja2-2.10 MarkupSafe-1.1.0 Werkzeug-0.14.1 click-7.0 flask-1.0.2 itsdangerous-1.1.0` but still same issue when I try to run the script

Comment: @Naufal your last comment is extremely interesting, when I browsed to `/usr/bin` and run `python2.7 -c "from flask import Flask, Response"`  it works! I do not understand what is happening.

Comment: @Naufal usr/bin is in PATH `$ echo $PATH` > 
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/abashir/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin`

Comment: from `/usr/bin` running `$ ls -l python2.7` maps to  `../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`

Comment: @AshrafBashir you'll need to reset your python PATH to /usr/bin/python2.7 then try running your script. Or, as you've got a local python interpreter, point your PATH to that interpreter then run your tokenize.py. Hopefully that should work.

Comment: @AshrafBashir did you manage to solve your issue?
BTW I disagree with the person who marked this as a duplicate question, it's not a duplicate question.